# SQL Pivot Table with Dates

Tags: sql, excel, crystal-reports

I have a table with inventory quantities

```
Date
StockCode
QtyonHand
```

I need to create a pivot table which I can pull into either Excel or Crystal which includes data for the previous 25 working days. 
The column headings need to be a formula so when I bring them into Crystal or Excel, I can have conditional formatting on them.

For example

```
Stock Code         
QtyonHand -25 days
QtyonHand-24days 
QtyonHand-23days    
QtyonHand-22days
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, post it in the question and say why it didn't work, please.

Comment: did't get your requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross-tab and save yourself some effort.

Place:

- `stock code` in rows summary section
- `date` in column summary section (group by day; DESC)
- `qtyonhand` in summarized field section

Change record-selection formula to be:

```
{table.date} >= (DataDate - 25)
```